# Split string returning an extra string at the end of the returned array

Tags: c#, split

I am trying to split a string using `;` as a delimiter.

My output is weird, why is there an empty string a the end of the returned array?

```cs
string emails = "bitebari@gmail.com;abcd@gmail.com;";
string[] splittedEmails = emails.TrimEnd().Split(';');

foreach (var email in splittedEmails)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Value is :" + email);
}
```

The console output looks like this:

> Value is: bitebari@gmail.com
>
> Value is: abcd@gmail.com
>
> Value is:

Comment: The last value is `""` (the empty string). The highlighted area is a display artifact. See `StringSplitOptions` or using a simple LINQ `Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))`.

Comment: Because there's an empty string after the last semicolon.

Comment: What about trimEnd()

Comment: TrimEnd will trim the end of each entry. You have to remove or ignore the empty entries

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `string.Split` method doesn't remove empty entries by default, anyhow you can tell it to do that, by providing it with the `StringSplitOptions`. Try to use your method with the `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` parameter.

```cs
string[] splittedEmails = emails.Split(';', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

---

Actually you should try to pass `;` to your `TrimEnd` method, since it will truncate white spaces otherwise. Therefore your string remains with the `;` at the end. This would result to the following:

```cs
string[] splittedEmails = emails.TrimEnd(';').Split(';');
```

---

Both of the solutions above work, it really comes to preference as the performance difference shouldn't be that high.

### Edit

This behavior is considered to be 'standard' at least in C#, let me quote the [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/parse-strings-using-split) for this one.

> This behavior makes it easier for formats like comma separated values (CSV) files representing tabular data. Consecutive commas represent a blank column.
>
> You can pass an optional StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries parameter to exclude any empty strings in the returned array. For more complicated processing of the returned collection, you can use LINQ to manipulate the result sequence.

Also there isn't just any special case for that.

Comment: I don't have anything after last ';' then where is the space coming from?

Comment: @Bikram It is *an empty string*, because the last component, after the last `;`, is *an empty string*.

Comment: Oh ok. That makes sense

Comment: Oh, I see what you did.. threw in a TrimEnd *and* a StringSplitOptions..

Comment: This doesn't answer the question asked.

Comment: @KennethK. You are right, I just noticed that the `TrimEnd` method was empty. I updated my answer.

Comment: I can fix the issue. The question is more like why is it doing it. After last ';' there is nothing for the string object to be set. Is this common to have this behvaiour?

Comment: @Bikram Check out my answer, I updated it for more information.

Comment: @BACON Thanks! You are right, I updated the answer.